# ERROR 1064 (42000) в простом SELECT

Tags: mysql, select

Не могу понять, что не так в первой строке запроса:

```
CREATE TABLE VSP_oper_data
    (`id` int, `Client_id` int, `Report_date` date, 
     `VSP_number` varchar(10), `Txn_type` varchar(10), `Txn_amount` float)
;

INSERT INTO VSP_oper_data
    (`id`, `Client_id`, `Report_date`, `VSP_number`, `Txn_type`, `Txn_amount`)
VALUES
    (1, 123, '2017.01.01', '123/013', 'debit', 50000),
    (2, 123, '2017.01.10', '555/013', 'debit', 500),
    (5, 123, '2017.03.10', '888/013', 'credit', 999),
    (7, 333, '2017.01.01', '123/013', 'debit', 9000),
    (8, 333, '2017.01.09', '666/013', 'debit', 400)
;


SELECT t1.Client_id, t1.Report_date, t1.Debit_amount, t1.Credit_amount, t2.Last_VSP
FROM
    (SELECT Client_id, MAX(Report_date) as Report_date,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Txn_type='debit' THEN Txn_amount ELSE 0 END) as Debit_amount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Txn_type='credit' THEN Txn_amount ELSE 0 END) as Credit_amount
    FROM VSP_oper_data
    GROUP BY Client_id, MONTH(Report_date), YEAR(Report_date)
    ) t1
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT Client_id, Report_date, VSP_number as Last_VSP
    FROM VSP_oper_data 
    WHERE Client_id = t1.Client_id and Report_date = t1.Report_date
    ORDER BY Report_date DESC
    LIMIT 1
    ) t2
on t1.Client_id = t2.Client_id and t1.Report_date = t2.Report_date
;
```

Возможно, есть и другие ошибки..

Comment: На первый взгляд вижу что при создании таблицы нет поля Debit_amount а к нему идет запрос в SELECT !!! Проверти может я ошибаюсь?

Comment: 1) MySQL понимает только один формат литерала даты. Без исключений. `YYYY-MM-DD`. Поэтому `'2017.01.01'` - это хрень, а не значение. 2) Баланс скобок не соблюдён.

Comment: Спасибо! Не заметил, что не полностью скопировал. Однако, проблему это не решает. Работает только без left join.

Comment: В последней строке в предложении ON вместо запятой должен быть логический оператор.

Comment: Это правда) Нашел еще немного ошибок. Добавлю в ответ. Вроде работает

Answer (score 0):

Вроде работает

```
SELECT t1.Client_id, t1.Report_date, t1.Debit_amount, t1.Credit_amount, t2.Last_VSP
FROM
    (SELECT Client_id, MAX(Report_date) as Report_date,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Txn_type='debit' THEN Txn_amount ELSE 0 END) as Debit_amount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Txn_type='credit' THEN Txn_amount ELSE 0 END) as Credit_amount
    FROM VSP_oper_data
    GROUP BY Client_id, MONTH(Report_date), YEAR(Report_date)
    ) t1
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT tmp.Client_id, tmp.Report_date, tmp.VSP_number as Last_VSP
    FROM VSP_oper_data tmp
    WHERE tmp.Client_id = Client_id and tmp.Report_date = Report_date
    ORDER BY tmp.Report_date DESC
    ) t2
ON t1.Client_id = t2.Client_id AND t1.Report_date = t2.Report_date
ORDER BY Client_id, Report_date
;
```